# Insert dynamic variable with multiple results to temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, temp-tables

I want to insert multiple records from dynamic variable into temp table, but I can't get successful. Can't get success with `INSERT`. Have you ideas how to do It?

I got following error: `A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.`

**PART OF CODE:**

```
-- Creating temp table
CREATE TABLE #tempTest
(
    one DATE,
    two ID,
    three NVARCHAR(60)
)
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(MAX)
-- Selecting 3 records (Date, Id, Email) to insert into temp table
SELECT @test = Date, Id, Email --throws error in this line
FROM   (SELECT [Date], [Id], [Email]
        FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FI.Id ASC) AS 'RowNum', CONVERT(DATE, FormV.[DateUpdated])   AS  [Date], FI.Id AS [Id]
            FROM        FormI                           AS  FI
            INNER JOIN  FormV                           AS  FormV
            ON          FI.FormVId  = FormV.Id
            INNER JOIN  NavArt                              AS  NA
            ON          FI.ArtId        = NA.Id
            WHERE       FI.WorkShiftId      = 10 
            ) withRownNum
        WHERE RowNum = 1

    ) a

-- Here I'm trying to insert these records to temp table, but unsuccessfully
INSERT INTO #tempTest VALUES(@colsConversion)
```

Comment: Why are you using a variable?. You can insert into #temTest select ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a variable. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTest
(
    one DATE,
    two ID,
    three NVARCHAR(60)
)
INSERT INTO #tempTest
SELECT  Date, Id, Email 
FROM   (SELECT [Date], [Id], [Email]
        FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FI.Id ASC) AS 'RowNum', CONVERT(DATE, FormV.[DateUpdated])   AS  [Date], FI.Id AS [Id]
            FROM        FormI                           AS  FI
            INNER JOIN  FormV                           AS  FormV
            ON          FI.FormVId  = FormV.Id
            INNER JOIN  NavArt                              AS  NA
            ON          FI.ArtId        = NA.Id
            WHERE       FI.WorkShiftId      = 10 
            ) withRownNum
        WHERE RowNum = 1

    ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot have a `select` where you assign some columns to a variables, but not all of them.  I don't see why you are assigning any, but you could also have variables for `@id` and `@email`.

If you want to create a temporary table, why not just do this?

```
    SELECT [Date], [Id], [Email]
    INTO #temptest
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FI.Id ASC) AS RowNum, CONVERT(DATE, FormV.[DateUpdated])   AS  [Date], FI.Id AS [Id]
        FROM        FormI                           AS  FI
        INNER JOIN  FormV                           AS  FormV
        ON          FI.FormVId  = FormV.Id
        INNER JOIN  NavArt                              AS  NA
        ON          FI.ArtId        = NA.Id
        WHERE       FI.WorkShiftId      = 10 
        ) withRownNum
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Note:  there are probably easier ways to write this subquery (using `top` for instance), but that is the answer to another question.